# Why Home.js and Cards.js are called many time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect

Here is my Console with console logged values.

[image: Console Screenshot]

Home Page is called 4 times i dont know why and Cards.js is also called even if i am checking for loading.

Here is my Home.js Code. I have tried removing dependency from effect hook but didn't worked.

```
const Home = () => {

  console.log('Home Page');

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const loading = useSelector(state => state.idFor.loading)
  const currentPage = useSelector((state) => state.idFor.currentPageHome)
  const homePosts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Home effect');
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    dispatch(getAllPosts(currentPage))
  }, [dispatch, currentPage])

  return (
    loading ? (
      <Loader type="ThreeDots" color="#000000" height={500} width={80} />
    ) : (
      <Cards posts={homePosts} setCurrentPage={setCurrentPageHome} currentPage={currentPage} pageName={"LATEST"} />
    )
  )
}
```

Here is my Cards.js code

```
const Cards = ({ posts, setCurrentPage, currentPage, pageName }) => {

  console.log('Cards.JS called', posts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  if (posts.length !== 0) {
    dispatch(setLoading(false))
  }

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    dispatch(setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1))
  }
  const handlePreviousPage = () => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true))
    dispatch(setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1))
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h4 className="page-heading">{pageName}</h4>
      <div className="card-container">
        {
          posts.map(post => <Card key={post._id} post={post} />)
        }
      </div>
      <div className="page-div">
        {currentPage !== 1 ? <span className="previous-page" onClick={handlePreviousPage}>&lt;</span>
          : null}
        <span className="next-page" onClick={handleNextPage}>&gt;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: function Home was called whenever the store changed, which means when you run dispatch, changed the store status like loading or currentPage, the functions would be called every time, it's fine, if you don't want to render many times, you can use useMemo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is from redux state.

```
  const loading = useSelector(state => state.idFor.loading)
  const currentPage = useSelector((state) => state.idFor.currentPageHome)
  const homePosts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)
```

When the redux state is updated, the Home component is called.

The each component is synced with redux state.

[image]

1. first loading
2. useEffect worked (home component, currentPage from redux)
3. loading updated (redux state)
4. data updated (redux state)

Thank you.

contact me [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPI1p.png) if you want learn more

Comment: Is it ok to have multiple render of Component or I have to fix it?

Comment: I think it is ok for only for 4 times. When the data is updated, the frontend state has to be updated, I think so.. :)